# Dynamic Buttons directions in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, button, direction

I made my UI with .xml, But I want to give the direction of the Button by dynamically.
For Example;

```
 <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button 
         android:id="@+id/backbutton"
         android:text="TEST123"
         android:layout_x="120px"
         android:layout_y="120px"
         android:layout_width="100px"
         android:layout_height="100px" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Then is my activity class I changed something by dynamically like that.

```
    AbsoluteLayout al = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
    Button t = new Button(this);
    t.setHeight(300);
    t.setWidth(300);
    t.setText("TEST123");
    // x y ???
    setContentView(al);
```

I've changed the height and width..but I couldn't find the way to changed x and y directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `setPadding(int top,int left,int right,int bottom)` method.

```
AbsoluteLayout al = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
    Button t = new Button(this);
    t.setHeight(300);
    t.setWidth(300);
    t.setText("TEST123");
    t.setPadding(120,120,0,0);
    setContentView(al);
```

I am not sure how your other elements of the screen are fitting, but I just assumed that button is the only element you have in your screen.

Comment: thank you soo muchhhhhhhhhh  :)
By the way do you know 1 dip= how many px?

Comment: You can use button.setLayoutparams(params) method also. Create a params object and use myparams.x = x coordinate and myparams.y = y coordinate.

Comment: Depend on the screen size. For 240 dpi screen, 1 dip = 1.5 pixels

Comment: If this solves your issue, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I'm trying this solution now;

utton.setLayoutparams(params) method also. Create a params object and use myparams.x = x coordinate and myparams.y = y coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

By the way do you know 1 dip= how many px?

From http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html:

Density-independent pixel (dp) - 
    A virtual pixel unit that applications can use in defining their UI, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.

The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, the baseline density assumed by the platform (as described later in this document). At run time, the platform transparently handles any scaling of the dp units needed, based on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: pixels = dps * (density / 160). For example, on 240 dpi screen, 1 dp would equal 1.5 physical pixels. Using dp units to define your application's UI is highly recommended, as a way of ensuring proper display of your UI on different screens.

Comment: I think it might be appropriate to accept the other answer as correct instead of mine. Since it answered the actual orginal question. Mine really could've been a comment but I wasn't sure if I'd have enough characters so I did it as an answer.